# Meaning of “knock it out of the park”

Tags: meaning, idioms, idiom-meaning

What does "knocks it out of the park" mean?

Example: "All should read this book as it knocks it out of the park"

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This question has already been asked on the [ELL site](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11783/are-there-any-expressions-equivalent-to-or-synonymous-with-knock-it-out-of-th).  It also could have been answered by a quick [google search](https://www.google.com/#q=knock+it+out+of+the+park).

Comment: [Google is not general reference.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/google-is-not-general-reference)

Answer (score 1):

To "knock it out of the park" is a reference to a homerun in baseball - where the batter hits the ball clear out of the ball-park.  It means to do extremely well.  See [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_English-language_idioms_derived_from_baseball#hit_it_out_of_the_park) for this and other baseball related idioms.

Comment: oh, i see, in allusion to a baseball action. i didn't know as it is not a popular sport here in our country. thanks for that sir.