# Two expressions in english

Tags: expressions, idioms

What is the meaning of these two expressions:

1. the pitch was now coming across the plate
2. I was staring at my chance to knock the ball out of the park

These two phrases was taken from the text below:

> With all the lessons I had learned from my trial-and-error days in the 1980s, the pitch was now coming across the plate, and I was staring at my chance to knock the ball out of the park.

Comment: Duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/147230/191178

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of “knock it out of the park”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147230/meaning-of-knock-it-out-of-the-park)

Answer (score 1):

In baseball, a player pitches (throws) the ball toward the other player, who stands at the plate and has a bat to hit the ball.

Pitch is a noun that refers to the baseball while it is in motion, approaching the player at the plate.

"Knock the ball out of the park" refers to the idea that a good player can hit the ball so hard that the ball flies out of the stadium. The stadium is often called a "park."

Comment: And note that the "plate" is "home plate" -- the base where the batter stands while waiting for the pitch.